# My Posts Not Visible In Google+ Community?

Tags: google-plus, google-plus-communities

I have joined a community and apparently recently I am unable to post to the Google+ community.

I mean I am able to post, I can see my post in my profile or the community but other people tend to be unable to see them.

And no, my posts are not awaiting for approval. I've been in the community before and posted tons of stuff into it and all of them were able to be seen by the public.

Comment: I get exactly the same problem. I dont have the answer only it seems to happen when i have been sharing lots of things. This morning i shared to 6 different communities. None of the posts seemed to have been shared even though i could see them in the communities. I tried deleting one post and sharing it a bit later and it worked.

Answer (score 1):

The posts are most likely in the queue for moderation. This the only way what you describe happens.

> And no, my posts are not awaiting for approval. I've been in the community before and posted tons of stuff into it and all of them were able to be seen by the public.

This does not mean anything. Posts historically being visible does not mean your current posts are not getting queued for moderation. The only way to know for sure though is for you to ask the community moderators.